# Storing 1 million rows in a collection, updating in an actor

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have an actor that in the background every hour downloads a CSV product file of about 1 million rows, and then it will loop through the CSV and mutate a collection.

Now in my play controllers, I will be displaying a subset of these 1 million rows to the website visitors.

I will be making a request to the actor to give me a copy of the collection.  **If I do this on a per page request basis, will this be a performance problem? Or is making a call like below very close to an assignment?**

```
val futProducts = myActor ? GetProducts
```

and my actor will have a collection of products that gets upated every hour or so.

```
var products: List[Product] = ...
```

**Update**

*How could I create a global reference to this `products` variable that I can reference in my play controllers, and then also be able to mutate in my actor.  I think this would be the best approach, but not sure how to do that.*

Comment: Lots of factors play into the performance. You might want to create `n` actors for each page if you're doing multipage requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would not solve this with a global reference to your `products` variable, since this would mean that you have a shared mutable state. I would go with your first approach of encapsulating the list of products in your actor like this:

```
import DataActor.{Page, Update}
import akka.actor.Actor

/**
  * Created by d058837 on 19.06.17.
  */
class DataActor extends Actor {

  var data: Seq[Int] = 1 to 100000
  val pageSize = 100

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Update =>
      updateData()
    case Page(page) =>
      sender() ! data.slice(pageSize * page, pageSize * page + pageSize)
  }

  def updateData() = {
    data = data.map(_ + 100)
  }

}

object DataActor {

  case object Update
  case class Page(page: Int = 0)
}
```

Which you can use as shown in this test:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestKit}
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class DataActorTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem")) with WordSpecLike with Matchers with ImplicitSender {

  "actor with data should" should {
    "update data and return pages" in {
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 3 seconds

      val dataActor = system.actorOf(Props[DataActor])

      val initialStateFuture = dataActor ? DataActor.Page(0)
      val initialState = Await.result(initialStateFuture, timeout.duration)
      initialState shouldBe (1 to 100)

      dataActor ! DataActor.Update

      val currentStateFuture = dataActor ? DataActor.Page(0)
      val currentState = Await.result(currentStateFuture, timeout.duration)
      currentState shouldBe (101 to 200)
    }
  }
}
```

I would definitely go with a paginated approach here, so that you don't move around your large list of products all the time.

To get additional performance you could use a cache in your controller, which gets invalidated when your DataActor updates its data, so that you only hit the actual data actor, when a new / unknown page is requested.